# PyCharm slow when connecting to python console

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I am trying to run a simple code in PyCharm - it takes like 30 seconds to connect to console every time I run the code and it is rather frustrating... Can someone recommend how I can speed this up?

I am getting this text at each start of the code:

```
C:\Users\Selected\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=56186
C:\Users\Selected\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\history.py:226: UserWarning: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved
  warn("IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved")
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\Selected\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject', 'C:/Users/Selected/PycharmProjects/pythonProject'])
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 7.19.0
```

PyCharm asked to install python interpreter at the start - did it install amd version for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the fact that it's AMD Python, as the python console starts up at that speed for me too, and I am using Pycharm Professional with Python 3.91 from the official [website](https://python.org/). My code (when I use Ctrl+Shift+F10) runs almost instantly. Your startup speed might be because you are using IPython.

Comment: so each time you run a code you need to wait 30 seconds for the console connection? I am actually on a xeon cpu....

Comment: no, when I click the "Python Console" it takes 30seconds, when I run code it runs practically instantly, but that shouldn't be because of Anaconda, as I have run code with Anaconda in it. also, my CPU is a Pentium with 4GB of RAM

Comment: I started spyder and the smae code starts instanteneusly.....not sure why the delay in pycharm - otherwise excellent platform

Comment: I don't know either, but Pycharm is a great IDE, it has quite a lot of tools

Comment: I am experiencing the same  and suspect ipython, how to change to python